# LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress in a function C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function

I have this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef HHOOK(__stdcall *f_funci)(int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD);
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        printf("could not load the dynamic library");
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // resolve function address here
    f_funci SetWindowsHookEx2 = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "SetWindowsHookExW");
    if (!SetWindowsHookEx2) {
        printf("could not locate the function SetWindowsHookExW");
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx2(WH_MOUSE_LL, my_function, hInstance, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I insert all this code in a function and just call it from the main to get `SetWindoesHookEx2` and use it later?

The problem here is that the returned value is `typedef HHOOK(__stdcall *f_funci)(int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD)` and it is a `HHOOK` structure that I don't know how to handle.

In resume I want somethig like:

```
int main(void) {
    SetWindowsHook2 = dynamyc_function("User32.dll", "SetWindowsHookExW", int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD)
    hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx2(WH_MOUSE_LL, my_function, hInstance, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't do this:

```
HHOOK load_hook(){
    typedef HHOOK(__stdcall *f_funci)(int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD);
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"User32.dll");

    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        printf("could not load the dynamic library");
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // resolve function address here
    f_funci SetWindowsHookEx2 = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "SetWindowsHookExW");
    if (!SetWindowsHookEx2) {
        printf("could not locate the function SetWindowsHookExW");
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }
    return SetWindowsHookEx2;
}
```

there are two errors: `'return' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'HHOOK'` and `'return' : cannot convert from 'f_funci' to 'HHOOK'` first one refering to `return EXIT_FAILURE;` and the second one to ´return SetWindowsHookEx2;´

Thank you.

Comment: Your first code looks right. HHOOK is the handle for the hook procedure.

Comment: Why do you need to link to `SetWindowsHookExW` dynamically?

Comment: I don't want that function being in the IAT

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having the function in your IAT. The only reason you wouldn't want it is if you are writing malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::wstring, HINSTANCE> libs;

template<typename T>
bool dynamyc_function(LPCWSTR libname, LPCSTR funcname, T *func)
{
    HINSTANCE hlib = libs[libname];
    if (!hlib)
    {
        hlib = LoadLibraryW(libname);
        if (!hlib)
        {
            wprintf(L"could not load the dynamic library %s! %d", libname, GetLastError());
            return false;
        }
        libs[libname] = hlib;
    }

    *func = (T) GetProcAddress(hlib, funcname);
    if (!*func)
    {
        printf("could not locate the function %s! %d", name, GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typedef HHOOK(__stdcall *f_funci)(int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD);

    // resolve function address here
    f_funci SetWindowsHookEx2;
    if (!dynamyc_function(L"User32.dll", "SetWindowsHookExW", &SetWindowsHookEx2))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    HHOOK hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx2(WH_MOUSE_LL, my_function, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hMouseHook)
    {
        printf("could not set hook! %d", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ...
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are only interested in a specific function, you can try something like this instead:

```
typedef HHOOK(__stdcall *f_funci)(int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD);

HHOOK __stdcall Impl_SetWindowsHookExW(int idHook, HOOKPROC lpfn, HINSTANCE hMod, DWORD dwThreadId);
HHOOK __stdcall Stub_SetWindowsHookExW(int idHook, HOOKPROC lpfn, HINSTANCE hMod, DWORD dwThreadId);
f_funci lpSetWindowsHookExW = &Stub_SetWindowsHookExW;

HHOOK __stdcall Impl_SetWindowsHookExW(int idHook, HOOKPROC lpfn, HINSTANCE hMod, DWORD 
{
    SetLastError(ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    return NULL;
}

HINSTANCE hUser32 = NULL;
HHOOK __stdcall Stub_SetWindowsHookExW(int idHook, HOOKPROC lpfn, HINSTANCE hMod, DWORD dwThreadId)
{
    if (!hUser32)
    {
        hUser32 = LoadLibraryW("User32.dll");
        if (!hUser32)
        {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            printf("could not load the dynamic library! %d", err);
            SetLastError(err);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    f_funci func = (f_funci) GetProcAddress(hUser32, "SetWindowsHookExW");
    if (!func)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("could not locate the function! %d", err);
        SetLastError(err);
        func = &Impl_SetWindowsHookExW;
    }

    lpSetWindowsHookExW = func;
    return func(idHook, lpfn, hMod, dwThreadId);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HHOOK hMouseHook = lpSetWindowsHookExW(WH_MOUSE_LL, my_function, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hMouseHook)
    {
        printf("could not set hook! %d", GetLastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ...
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling a function `dynload` that doesn't exist?

Comment: `dynload()` is a *Nix function that does not exist on Windows. But you will see that I changed the function name to `dynamyc_function` instead to match the OP's question.

Comment: `main` is still using the name `dynload`.  And I thought the equivalent Unix functions were `dlopen` and `dlsym`.

Comment: I fixed the typo in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass types as runtime arguments in C or C++.

In C++, you can use templates which support type arguments.  Something like:

```
auto SetWindowsHook2 = dynamic_function<HHOOK(__stdcall *)(int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD)>(L"User32.dll", "SetWindowsHookExW");
```

where the function is defined as:

```
template<typename FuncPtr>
FuncPtr dynamic_function(const wchar_t* dllname, const char* fn)
{
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibraryW(dllname);

    if (!hDLL) {
        printf("could not load the dynamic library");
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return nullptr;
    }

    // resolve function address here
    auto pf = (FuncPtr)GetProcAddress(hDLL, fn);
    if (!pf) {
        printf("could not locate the function %s", fn);
        printf("%d", GetLastError());
        return nullptr;
    }

    return pf;
}
```

Note that this leaks library reference counts, so it really isn't a good solution.  A better way would be to have an RAII class for the DLL that releases the reference (with `FreeLibrary`) in its destructor.  And `dynamic_function` could be a member function of the DLL-referent object.  You'd then be responsible for keeping that object alive as long as you need the function pointers you got from it.

Comment: What do you mean with this leaks library reference?

Comment: @user1618465: When you're done with a library, you're supposed to call `FreeLibrary`.  But the caller has no way to do so, the handle `hDll` went out of scope.

Comment: Okey. thank you for your response. I'll mark it as correct. Just an offtopic: why does the people vote as negative my post? Is it not correctlly explained?

Comment: @user1618465: At first it looked like you didn't try to solve the problem yourself.  Now it sounds like you didn't read the error message.

Comment: @user1618465: And your comment sounds like you're writing malware; that may bring more downvotes.